# How to save a 30- dimensional numpy array to human readable txt file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I'm new to python and have a question. I have following array and want to save it to a txt file.

`data_arr = np.array([[str(Drahtnummer).zfill(4), str(Lagenummer).zfill(4), Position_in_Lage, "{0:07.2f}".format(x_mid), "{0:07.2f}".format(y_mid), "{0:07.2f}".format(z_0),"{0:06.3f}".format(r_g), "{0:06.3f}".format(r)]])`

print(data_arr) looks like:

```
[['0001' '0001' '01.01' '0002.32' '0002.00' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0002' '0001' '02.01' '0002.92' '0005.95' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0003' '0001' '03.01' '0003.52' '0009.91' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0004' '0001' '04.01' '0004.12' '0013.86' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0005' '0001' '05.01' '0004.72' '0017.82' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0006' '0002' '01.02' '0006.05' '0003.46' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0007' '0002' '02.02' '0006.65' '0007.41' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0008' '0002' '03.02' '0007.25' '0011.37' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0009' '0002' '04.02' '0007.85' '0015.32' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0010' '0003' '01.03' '0009.77' '0004.92' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0011' '0003' '02.03' '0010.37' '0008.87' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0012' '0003' '03.03' '0010.97' '0012.83' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0013' '0003' '04.03' '0011.57' '0016.78' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0014' '0004' '01.04' '0012.90' '0002.42' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0015' '0004' '02.04' '0013.50' '0006.37' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0016' '0004' '03.04' '0014.10' '0010.33' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0017' '0004' '04.04' '0014.70' '0014.28' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0018' '0005' '01.05' '0016.62' '0003.88' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0019' '0005' '02.05' '0017.22' '0007.83' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0020' '0005' '03.05' '0017.82' '0011.79' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0021' '0005' '04.05' '0018.42' '0015.74' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0022' '0006' '01.06' '0020.35' '0005.33' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0023' '0006' '02.06' '0020.95' '0009.29' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0024' '0006' '03.06' '0021.55' '0013.24' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0025' '0006' '04.06' '0022.15' '0017.20' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0026' '0007' '01.07' '0023.47' '0002.84' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0027' '0007' '02.07' '0024.07' '0006.79' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0028' '0007' '03.07' '0024.67' '0010.75' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0029' '0007' '04.07' '0025.27' '0014.70' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']
 ['0030' '0008' '01.08' '0027.20' '0004.29' '0001.00' '02.000' '01.000']]
```

This format without the edges and seperated by ";" would be perfect.

As I am right, i have a 2-dimensional array with 30 rows and 8 cols each.

How can i convert it into a readable txt file? I tried the often quotet "cut it into slices", but i really don't know in my case how to reshape it. And i tried to put it to an own save_file function in case that makes any differences^^

like

```
def save_file(data_arr):
    np.savetxt("OWA.txt", data_arr)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You need to show what you want your text file to look like.

Comment: You might want to use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: I updated the post!

Comment: No I need a .txt file -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this format.

```
a_file = open("test.txt", "w")
for row in an_array:
    np.savetxt(a_file, row)

a_file.close()
```

and when you open your file. You can try this

```
original_array = np.loadtxt("test.txt").reshape(dims)

print(original_array)
```

Comment: `  def save_file(data_arr):  
    a_file = open("test.txt", "w")  
    for row in data_arr:  
        np.savetxt(a_file, row)  
    a_file.close()  `  opens a test.txt file but its empty and the program still exits witout finishing(it does without the save_files function)

Comment: @Sven Lankeshofer Did you make empty test.txt file before execution because the above thread was for reference. After creating you have to run your code.

Comment: No, i didn't. But now there is the file and if i run the code it still doesn't fill it and the programm crashes, but there is only this/no information why: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409). -.-

Comment: when i manually created a new testfile and then started the programm it worked! Another way to ge around this problem was using "w+" in open("test.txt","w+")